# barplot x-axis labels with hierarchical grouping variables in separate rows

Tags: r, axis-labels, bar-chart

In Excel, with data organized like so:

```
                                              Bare NP                   Singular-Marked NP               Plural-Marked NP   
                                    BrP Speakers    AmE Speakers    BrP Speakers    AmE Speakers    BrP Speakers AmE Speakers
Plural Interpretation               0.005747126 0.006896552         0.194117647 0.124567474         0.872093023 0.985815603
Plural & Singular Interpretation    0.649425287 0.910344828         0.029411765 0.051903114         0.127906977 0.014184397
Singular Interpretation             0.344827586 0.082758621         0.776470588 0.823529412         0           0
```

I am able to produce a stacked barchart that looks like this:

[image]

Is there an easy way to reproduce the way that the x-axis is partitioned into the separate conditions (*i.e.*, "Bare NP", "Singular-Marked NP", and "Plural-Marked NP") using `R`?

All that I can come up with at the moment is this:

```
pluralInterp <- c(0.005747126,0.006896552,0.194117647,0.124567474,0.872093023,0.985815603)

pluralAndSingInterp <- c(0.649425287,0.910344828,0.029411765,0.051903114,0.127906977,0.014184397)

singInterp <- c(0.344827586,0.082758621,0.776470588,0.823529412,0,0)

a  <- rbind(pluralInterp,pluralAndSingInterp,singInterp)

colnames(a) <- c("Bare NP ~ BrP Speakers",
                 "Bare NP ~ AmE Speakers",
                 "Singular-Marked NP ~ BrP Speakers",
                 "Singular-Marked NP ~ AmE Speakers",
                 "Plural-Marked NP ~ BrP Speakers",
                 "Plural-Marked NP ~ AmE Speakers"
                 )

barplot(a,
        col=c("blue","red","purple"),
        ylab="Frequency of Interpretation",
        xlab="Form of NP and Native Language",
        main="Frequency of BrP and AmE Interpretations of NPs in Neutral Environments"
        )
```

Which produces the following graph:

[image]

Comment: I know it's not exactly what's required but I simply `paste`d the strings to make the x-axis and to retain the order of the factors I used `match(factorVar, levels(factorVar))` to produce explicit ordering within the `paste` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit of manual adjustment of the margins and calling `axis()` twice can get you there.
Saving a barplot like `bp <- barplot(...)` saves the midpoints of each bar for future reference.

```
oldpar <-par(mar=c(7,5.1,4.1,2.1))

bp <- barplot(a,
        col=c("blue","red","purple"),
        ylab="Frequency of Interpretation",
        xlab="",
        main="Frequency of BrP and AmE Interpretations \n of NPs in Neutral Environments",
        axisnames=FALSE
       )
```

You can then use the values stored in `bp` to align things properly. You can align the group and sub-group labels using the `line=...` argument to `axis()`

```
avgpts <- tapply(bp,rep(1:3,each=2),mean)
grps <- c("Bare NP","Singular-Marked NP","Plural-Marked NP")
subgrps <- c("BrP","AmE")
axis(1,at=bp,labels=rep(subgrps,3), cex.axis=0.7)
axis(1,at=avgpts,labels=grps, cex.axis=0.7,line=1.5,lwd=0)

title(xlab="Form of NP and Native Language",line=4.5)
```

Resulting in:

[image]