# "Nested" barplots, with multiple levels of grouping

Tags: r, bar-chart

How can I group bars in a barplot by a third variable?

[image]

I would like to achieve this in base R, without, for example, ggplot2, as in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37228134/r-barplot-with-n-groups-which-stacks-2-values). In [another related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18776078/barplot-x-axis-labels-with-hierarchical-grouping-variables-in-separate-rows) the groups of groups are labeled, but not (visually) grouped – as in my example above –, making the plot difficult to read.

---

Sample data:

```
groups = c("A", "B")
choices = c("orange", "apple", "beer")
supergroups = c("fruits", "non-fruits")
dat <- data.frame(
    group = rep(groups, c(93, 94)),
    choice = factor(c(
            rep(choices, c(51, 30, 12)),
            rep(choices, c(47, 29, 18))
        ),
        levels = choices
    ),
    supergroup = c(
        rep(supergroups, c(81, 12)),
        rep(supergroups, c(76, 18))
    )
)
barplot(table(dat), beside = TRUE)
```

Which returns the error:

```
Error in barplot.default(table(dat), beside = TRUE) : 
  'height' must be a vector or a matrix
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [barplot x-axis labels with hierarchical grouping variables in separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18776078/barplot-x-axis-labels-with-hierarchical-grouping-variables-in-separate-rows)

Comment: @user8183921 I doubt that it is the _only_ way to do it. You might consider edit your question, and describe (with a simple sketch?) in which way the linked Q&A doesn't give you the desired result. A side note: It is slightly annoying that `barplot` doesn't have an `at` argument, like `boxplot` has,  i.e. "numeric vector giving the locations where the boxplots should be drawn". Cheers.

Comment: ggplot solution: `ggplot(dat, aes(choice, fill=group)) + geom_bar(width=.5) + facet_grid(~supergroup, scales="free_x", space="free")`

Comment: Thank you, @Henrik, I added a brief explanation as to how the answer to that possible duplicate question does not answer my question. I visual example of what I want to achieve is already part of my question.

Comment: Thank you, @AdamQuek. I don't have ggplot2 installed, so I cannot quickly test your code and look at the result, but the reason that I want to avoid ggplot2 is that plots made with that library look so different from the other plots in my papers which I created using base R, that I have to spend endless time fiddling with the settings for ggplot2 to achieve a base R look. Also, the overwhelmingly many options in ggplot2 feel too much like using Word to me ... ;-)